# IOS webshop payment local encryption

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, payment-gateway

I have a working webshop on a webside (written in php) what I need to implement into IOS. The service what I use (CIB bank ecommerce) does not provide API for IOS. I have a php code for encrypt and decrypt data because it need to be encrypted when I pass it to the bank server (where the user checkout). Than the bank push back some data what I need to decrypt.

**My question is** can I use the available php encrypt code on my server? Is it safe to pass data into server where I can encrypt, get back and pass for the bank server? Or I need to implement the encryption method into the IOS app locally?

Thanks (and sorry if it should be straightforward, but I am beginner)

p.s.
(if it is safe because of https why banks need another type of encryption)

Comment: What kind of encryption? In general, you should typically not do encryption on the client using a private key or secret, because a malicious user can gain access to this secret.

Comment: The base is 3DES CBC. So you suggest the local method? How can anyone gain access if I already have the key on the server because a php webshop exist there?

Comment: No. When I say "client," I'm referring to the iOS device.

Comment: My bad. So the https -> php -> https combination looks good?

Comment: I can't say for sure because I don't know your exact use case, but I'd say so.